# Error handling when looping files in a folder and using subprocedures

Tags: vba, loops, error-handling

I loop through files in a folder and run some actions via two subprocedures (one of those subprocedures calls other subprocedures).

There are instances in which a file doesn't have the right formatting or an error causes any of the subprocedures to fail.

I would like to add error handling so that it skips the file but that it saves the name of the file in a txt or msg box showing which files were not processed.

```vb
Sub PL1BatchFiles()

    Dim folderName As String, eApp As Excel.Application, fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, currWs As Worksheet, currWb As Workbook
    Dim fDialog As Object: Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    Set currWb = ActiveWorkbook: Set currWs = ActiveSheet
    Dim lcolPS As Integer
    Dim lcolTC As Integer
    Dim lcolRTD As Integer
    Dim NumberPS As Integer
    Dim TC_Number As Integer
    Dim RTD_Number As Integer
    Dim fileName2 As String
    
    'Select folder in which all files are stored
    fDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = currWb.Path
    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
        folderName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    'Create a separate Excel process that is invisibile
    Set eApp = New Excel.Application:  eApp.Visible = True
    eApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    eApp.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Search for all files in folder [replace *.* with your pattern e.g. *.xlsx]
    fileName = Dir(folderName & "\*Steady*.xlsx")
    'fileName = "C:\Users\mconejoh\OneDrive - Intel Corporation\Documents\Lidded BGA\ETB4_noTS_lid_5W_CPU_heavy.xlsx"
    Do While fileName <> ""
        'Update status bar to indicate progress
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & folderName & "\" & fileName
        Set wb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(folderName & "\" & fileName)
        eApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        eApp.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        'Get the PS, RTD and TC number:
        lcolPS = wb.Worksheets("Power").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        NumberPS = (lcolPS - 1) / 3
        lcolTC = wb.Worksheets("Thermocouples").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        TC_Number = lcolTC - 1
        lcolRTD = wb.Worksheets("RTDS").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        RTD_Number = lcolRTD - 1
        
        'Run each subprocedure
        Call RTS_powerSheet(wb, NumberPS)
        Call PL1_only(wb, RTD_Number, TC_Number, NumberPS)
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        'Close opened worbook w saving, change as needed
        fileName = Dir()
        
        eApp.DisplayAlerts = True
        eApp.ScreenUpdating = True

    Loop
    eApp.Quit
    Set eApp = Nothing
    'Clear statusbar and notify of macro completion
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox "Completed executing macro on all workbooks"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: IMHO this is too general but a genearl answer would be to re-write the subs as function and return false if if fails. In this case add the filename to a collection or array in order to have all files where the functions failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You re-write your subs as functions. Then a structure how to collect all the files where the subs failed could look like that

```
    Sub fileLoop()
    
        Dim Foldername, fileName
        
        Dim colProblem As New Collection
     
        fileName = Dir(Foldername & "\*Steady*.xlsx")
        Do While fileName <> ""
    
            If Not Dosth(fileName) Then
                colProblem.Add fileName
            End If
    
            fileName = Dir()
    
        Loop
    
    End Sub
    
    Function Dosth(fileName) As Boolean
    
        On Error GoTo EH
        ' ... Code here
        
        ' In case everything went fine
        ' function did its job
        Dosth = True
        
        Exit Function

     EH:

        Dosth = false

    End Function
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I only had a chance to try it today. It worked perfectly, thank you so much!